# Pine script (Tradingview) - read out exchange name

Tags: pine-script

I'm completely new to programming in general and pine script. I am trying to write an indicator which gives me price performance of a stock/symbol in relation to a stock index that is relevant to the market/exchange the stock symbol trades at. For example, if I look at the American Coca-Cola (ticker 'KO' on NYSE), I want the relative price performance to the SPX ('SPX500'), if I look at the Japanese eGuarantee (ticker '8771' on TSE), I want the relative performance to the Nikkei 225 ('NKY').

I have put together the following, with my symbol ticker of interest 'a' and the relative index ticker to compare to 'b'.

```
study("RS", shorttitle="RS") 
//@version=2

a = tickerid

exchange = tostring(syminfo.prefix)

if (exchange="TSE")
b = input("NKY", type=symbol)
/// X ///
else b = input("SPX500", type=symbol)

as = security(a, period, close)
bs = security(b, period, close)
plot(as/bs, title="CRS", color=#FF7F00,linewidth=3) 

len2=20
out2 = ema(as/bs, len2)
plot(out2,title="EMA20",color=#FF7F00,linewidth=2)
```

On the part indicated with '/// X ///', I want to add in the specific exchanges and the relative indices once it works in a minimal example, but even for this short script I am getting the error

***"line 8: no viable alternative at input 'exchange'"*** - a quick google search points to various errors but nothing specific to pinescript (java, python, ...).

Has anyone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the v4 instead, as `syminfo.prefix` is only available for the v3 and v4. `syminfo.prefix` will return the symbol prefix as a string, therefore you don't need to use `tostring`.

For the rest of the code, you will run with many complications. I would suggest learning the basics of the v4.

Answer (score -2):

Had same quest, found this solution

https://www.tradingview.com/script/jaUjYI2G-Relative-Strength-Auto-Comparison/

Add this

```
ex == "TSE" ? "NKY" :
```

Comment: There is no mention or explanation of that anywhere in your linked page. Also, this ternary statement is incomplete. There is no apparent place for the OP to add this in the code.

Comment: The entire working body of code is on that linked page.